# How does this function call this closure when each returns just a single Int?

Tags: swift, function, closures

I find this code very confusing:

```
let myClosure = { (number1: Int, number2: Int) -> Int in
    return number1 * number2
}

func useClosure(closure: (Int, Int) -> Int) {
    let result = closure(2, 3)
    print(result) // prints 6
}

useClosure(closure: myClosure)
```

The func `useClosure` takes 2 Ints with the parameter name `closure` which is the closure `myClosure` but `myClosure` has only 1 returned Int, so how can it be the parameter of `useClosure`?

And where is `myClosure` getting `number1` and `number2` from? From `useClosure`?

On the surface, it seems 2 and 3 are being passed to `myClosure` but it's not clear how that is happening.

It all seems circular to me and makes little sense.

I haven't really tried anything to "resolve" this as it doesn't really need resolution. The code works fine.  I'm just struggling to understand it – from where I am in my journey as a developer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the declaration of `myClosure` - or even better, option+click on it - you'll see that its type is `(Int, Int) -> Int`. Which is exactly the type of the input argument `useClosure` expects.

That type signature represents a closure, which takes two `Int`s as input and returns an `Int`.

> The func useClosure takes 2 Ints with the parameter name closure

`useClosure` takes a **closure** as its input, not a pair of `Int`s as you claim.

You are passing the values inside `useClosure` to the input argument, `closure`.

When looking at type signatures, everything on the left-hand side of `->` represents the input arguments to the function, while everything on its right hand side represents the return type.